# Array bounds checking techniques in C or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

My goal is to prevent index out of bounds conditions for the lower bound when using a variable as a subscript to an array. In other words, I'd like to limit the integer variable values to >= 0. Sort of similar to an absolute value, except instead of making a negative number positive, it would make a negative number zero.

Is there any better method of doing this than using a macro such as:

```
#define gte0(value) (value < 0) ? 0 : value
```

and then wrapping my variables representing an index with this macro when I access an array element? Is there a standard practice bounds checking other than doing it manually in every place in your code before you access an array element with a variable representing the index?

I'm looking for any solutions in C or Objective-C.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the situation where you need items less than zero to become zero? You might want to reconsider your code there, instead.

Comment: I'd suggest instead that you insert assertions that the array index is >= zero.

Comment: I agree, the best strategy is just to do a bounds check at that location in the code so it's crystal clear what is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require `unsigned int` or `NSUInteger` primitives for indices. You'll then be guaranteed a value greater than or equal to zero, up to `UINT_MAX` or whatever `limits.h` defines, and you just need to check the upper bound.

Comment: This won't help.  If you've somehow constructed a situation where you're calculating an array index as negative, pretending it's unsigned will still cause massive issues.

Comment: That's why you check the upper bound.

Comment: Fair enough.  But this doesn't really answer the OP's question, which is about automated bounds checking.

Comment: I think it should be possible to write a macro or category helper method that takes two arguments, array pointer and index, and return either the object-at-index or nil. This would essentially replace -objectAtIndex: with something like -objectAtValidatedIndex:

Comment: In any case, if you're not already using NSUInteger with an NSArray, now is probably as good a time to start as any. You can instead catch NSRangeException, as a way to deal with bad indices. See the NSArray documentation.

Comment: I figured an unsigned int and proper bounds checking was the way to go, I was just wondering if there was a clever shortcut I hadn't known about. I try not to use ObjC's exception handling features except for truly exceptional circumstances. In this scenario, it's simply better to check the bounds where required without trying to shortcut it using a macro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this automatically in C.

Comment: Probably because he didn't like that fact :-)